# How to add Facebook's email to scope?

Tags: facebook, email, scope

I know how to get standard email (cezary.kowalski@o2.pl).
How to get Facebook's email (cezary.kowalski.56481@facebook.com)?

[Screen](http://scr.hu/0fde/iidir)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's email id is nothing but the facebook users `username` with the domain `facebook.com` So if you just have the `username` of any facebook user you will have his/her facebook email too. Its just `username@facebook.com`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. You will get the primary email of the user. Previously, the users were able not to share their direct emails with apps and hence a proxied email is shared instead. But I don't see this option anymore though.

Anyway, you can have a quick look at the user FQL table to check what are the fields available:

```
SELECT contact_email, email, email_hashes, proxied_email FROM user WHERE uid=me()
```

You can also try it yourself [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20contact_email,%20email,%20email_hashes,%20proxied_email%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me%28%29).